# Find proper noun in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am intrested in finding proper noun in a string but not if they are the first word in the sentence or the word is the fist word in the string. So for example I want to match the words Lipsum and Adipiscing and NOT "Lorem" because it is the first word and not "Consectetur" because it is the first word in the sentence.

Lorem Lipsum DOLOR ament blah blah. Consectetur Adipiscing elit ament blah

I did something like this

```
var txt = $.trim($('#wrapper').text());
var newVal = '';
txt = txt.split(' ');

var rg= new RegExp("^[A-Z][a-z]{2,}");

        for(var i=0; i < txt.length; i++) {

               if(txt[i].search(rg) === -1) {

                newVal += txt[i] + " ";

            }   
            else {

                if (i == 0) {
                    newVal += txt[i] + " ";

                }else{

                newVal += "<span class='highlight'>"+txt[i]+"</span> ";

                }
            }

        }
        $('#wrapper').html(newVal);
```

this works and highlights the proper nouns but it also highlights the first word of the sentence. test at http://jsfiddle.net/ariyo/SU32g/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You really mean "capitalized words".  xkcd, for example, is a "proper noun" but is not capitalized, even at the beginning of a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it about like this:

```
var re = /([A-Za-z]\s+)([A-Z][a-z]+(\s+[A-Z][a-z]+)*)/g;

$('#wrapper').html($('#wrapper').html().replace(re, '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span>'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aeCrG/3/

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks so much. I would really appreciate it if you could explain your regex. I really want to understand what's going on there.

Comment: One thing I noticed though. It highlights "word" in "WordPress" is there a way to have it not do that? Thanks

Comment: If you are going to define "proper nouns" in some other manner, then a simple regular expression may no longer do the job. In most cases, you will end up manually parsing the content. Have you tried hyphenated words? Abbreviations? Phrases like "... for Smith & Co. ..."?

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about that. Like @harpo suggested I guess I really meant capitalized words. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @AriyoShahry: Then it would need a loop like you have now. I'll edit it in a minute.

Comment: If you only care about the first letter of the word being capital (e.g. want to match ALLCAPITALS or CamelCase) you can use `/(\w\s+)([A-Z]\w+(\s+[A-Z]\w+)*)/`